# Enabling port for tcp in Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, wcf-binding, tcplistener, net.tcp

I have created a Windows WCF Service and I want to host it inside Azure VM.

The service is locally running fine inside the VM, but when attempting to access the service outside of the VM, I cannot connect to the service at the specified port.

While requesting the service, I'm getting the following error:

```
SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...
```

Also, while pinging the VM through the command prompt with public ip, I'm getting `Request timed out`.

I have enabled the port for TCP in Azure inbound rules as well as in VM firewall inbound rules. The VM is Windows Server.

How can I access the service running in the VM from another system?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. check application is running on the port you exposed
2. check windows level firewall allows traffic on that port from your destination
3. check NIC level NSG allows traffic on that port from your destination
4. check subnet level NSG allows traffic on that port from your destination
5. you might also have Azure Firewall\UDR\NVA in the networking setup, check those as well (this is highly unlikely if you are not running an enterprise grade setup).